# What is the difference between '/' operator and "%/%" operator in r programming language?

Tags: r

I came across below code

```
v <- c( 2,5.5,6)
t <- c(8, 3, 4)
print(v/t)
print(v%/%t)
```

In what way 3rd and 4th lines of code are different?

Comment: `/` is division while `%/%` is integer division

Comment: I do not understand how you can ask if the 3rd and 4th code lines are the same, their results are different.

Comment: @Monic I first saw the example of two vectors which has only 0's and 1's .Since I was new to r programming, I am in tense and immediately posted this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/` does the usual division.

Regarding `%/%`, the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Arithmetic.html) states:

> `%%` indicates `x mod y` and `%/%` indicates integer division.  It
>        is guaranteed that `x == (x %% y) + y * ( x %/% y )` (up to
>        rounding error) unless `y == 0` […]

To find the documentation for such operators, enter the following on the R console:

```
help("%/%")
```

Comment: I recommend the help function with standard evaluation: help("%/%")

Comment: I prefer it for didactic reasons ... With ? you need to know when to use backtics and stuff. Personally, I use RStudio's documentation pane.

Answer (score 3):

Both are arithmetic operators. The first one is division, the second is integer division. See here: https://www.statmethods.net/management/operators.html

```
> 10/3
[1] 3.333333
> 10%/%3
[1] 3
```

In addition, there is also modulus division (x %% y)

```
> 10%%3
[1] 1
```

That's all I know about division operators :-)